# vuex: why calling mutation from within a namespaced module requires a prefix?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following vuex config

```
import listing from '@/store/modules/listing'
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules:
    {
        listing: listing,

    },
```

and the listing module code looks like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const listing = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        listingAllItems: [],
        listingSelectedItems: [],       
    },
    mutations: {
        updateListingAllItems(state, param) {
        },
    },
    actions: {
        getListingItems(context, param) {
            var tempThis = this;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var url = 'http://WS/';
                Vue.http.get(url).then(response => {
                    tempThis.commit('updateListingAllItems', response.data);
                }).catch(error => reject(error));
            })
        },
    },
    getters: {}
}

export default listing
```

when calling **this.commit('updateListingAllItems', response.data)** I'm getting **[vuex] unknown mutation type: updateListingAllItems**.

the [vuex guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) says

> Namespaced getters and actions will receive localized getters,
>   dispatch and commit. In other words, you can use the module assets
>   without writing prefix in the same module

Why am I getting the error message then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an action method `this` is the store. Your code commits an non-prefixed mutation on the store instance.

If you change

`tempThis.commit('updateListingAllItems', response.data);`

to

`context.commit('updateListingAllItems', response.data);`

you'll get what you expect.